# How to group data by datetime in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data which looks like below

```
data = [(u'Del', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0), 59L), (u'Bom', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0), 449L), (u'Del', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0), 0L), (u'Bom', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0), 45L)]
```

Now I want to sub group the data based on time such that it looks something like this

```
data = [
         [(u'Del', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0), 59L), (u'Bom', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0), 449L)] 
        ,[(u'Del', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0), 0L), (u'Bom', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0), 45L)]
       ]
```

As you can see, now it is a list of lists where there are two lists inside a list where each list contains similar `datetime`. For example the first sublist looks like this

```
[(u'Del', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0), 59L), (u'Bom', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0), 449L)]
```

Here the items of the first sublist contains similar date time which is `datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0)`

The second sublist looks like this

```
[(u'Del', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0), 0L), (u'Bom', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0), 45L)]
```

Here the items of the first sublist contains similar date time which is `datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0)`

I can sort the data based on `datetime` by doing something like this (though data is already sorted by `datetime` in this case)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import psycopg2

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df[1])
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

But I can't group them based on the sorted time. How do I achieve this using `pandas`?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your example data, please edit your post.

Comment: @eva-vw The data is correct. You have to use imports that I have used to wrangle the data.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a sample of the actually dataframe you're trying to group. A [mcve] should include all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue (and _only_ the necessary code), as well as a sample input and output.

Comment: @G.Anderson I have now fixed the data example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['place','date','value']


output = [x[1].values for x in df.groupby(date)]
```

output looks like:

```
[[[u'Del', Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00'), 59], [u'Bom', Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00'), 449]], [[u'Del', Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'), 0], [u'Bom', Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'), 45]]]
```

Comment: just exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!